# 18650 cells vs 3.7v Polymer "flat packs"?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

I am working on putting together a custom powerbank for running an MMDVM.
I have been planning to use 18650 cells. The plan being a configuration of 2 sets of 2 parallel cells, connected in series.
This should deliver roughly 8.5v which I could buck down to 5v for the device.

While researching charging boards, I noticed one mfg recommended Polymer packs over 18650 cells. I am working with the following assumptions, and would like to see if I am more or less thinking straight.

1. 18650 cells will be able to deliver more current both in peak and continuous usage.
2. Polymer flat packs being 3.7v would require less shift in voltage (aka less heat). But spacially do not deliver the same amphours as the 18650. Hence less desirable.

Either configuration would be "acceptable" by practical standards. However the 18650 cells would be a more efficient, and durable solution.

Another concern would be charging these packs. For the portability and usability in the field; I want to be able to charge these packs from a 5v solar panel I have. I suppose I could always try making a larger panel set to deliver more volts, but I'd rather not create additional projects.

I know lithium cells are extremely finicky. I don't need a lecture on alkali chemistry (sorry, reaction to a different post. Wherein someone assumed I figured I could jam direct 5v onto the cells; and not expect to have my house burn down)
I know that in physics there is the "no free lunch" principle. Aka if I put 5v into a 50v capacitor, I'm only going to get 5v back. However charging a 9v battery pack from 5v is going to be problematic (I think). The cells are combined to push 9v outgoing, but the individual cells are still essentially 5v. In order to charge the pack from a 5v source, would I have to isolate the packs (diodes can be quite useful at times). Then bridge 2 5v charging circuits into each of the packs that are in series?
Or am I over thinking this, and the logic of the cells being 5v is all that matters when it's incoming voltage?

Finally, does anyone have a recommended charging controller? I've found a few that are BMS plus charging board combined, but have mixed to negative reviews

I just wanted to ensure my thoughts are more or less on track and I'm not misunderstanding some aspect of this (honestly, I'm assuming that I am).

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say that lipos would need less "shift in voltage"? What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Hearth Sounds like temperature vs voltage, but 18650 cases are thermally conducting steel with lower surface area and flat packs are thermally insulating plastic pouches but higher surface area

Comment: @Hearth, what DKNguyen said. More simply put, the voltage difference between stepping the 9v down to 5v vs lipos only providing 7v hence only reducing 2v to meet the Raspberry Pi. Poth solutions have their own method of mitigating the thermal differences. Especially since this is going to all sit in a 3DPrinted enclosure, dumping 4v into to the air could be problematic at higher current rates.

Comment: Exactly what voltage do you think an 18650 is? The chemistry is essentially identical to lipos, you have the same range of approximately 4.2 to 3.0 volts over the discharge cycle. And whether 7 volt or 9 volt input is more efficient depends on your power converter, it's not always lower is better. And that's not what DKNguyen meant; they were talking about the fact that the battery voltage is a function of temperature as well, a hotter cell will produce a higher voltage.

Comment: I'm not sure where your "9V" comes from, but 18650 is a just a different form factor for the same LiIon/LiPo technology that's in a flatpack and AFAIK usually come in 3.7V. For dropping any voltage to 5V you should use a switching (buck) supply that can drop an input voltage to the required output voltage much more efficiently than a linear supply.

Comment: OP, in what you describe there is no explicit dumping going on unless you are using linear regulators, which if you are then you have failed to mention at all.

Comment: @StarCat, I was basing that on having seen an 18650 that was marked as 4.7v. I just checked the cells I have and they indeed are 3.7v, good to know the other cells were an anomaly.

DKNguyen, After further reading I saw that DC-DC converters are more efficient and don't suffer from the same thermal issues... good to know...

Answer (score 0):

The way everyone and their dog would do it is a boost regulator and a single 3.7V cell. Series cell combinations require a charge balancer, so that’s way more complicated than just having a boost regulator.

The cells can be connected in parallel without much trouble if you need to – it’s the series connection that’s problematic. The parallel connection requires fusing for each cell, and they need to be fully charged before they are inserted into the pack. I.e. you can’t be mindless about cell swapping.

3.7V-to-5V boost circuits are a dime a dozen almost. You can buy one for a couple bucks from AdaFruit, eBay, etc.

You’re way, way over complicating the whole thing.

As for a charge controller: again, dime a dozen USB-to-3.7V chargers abound.

But still: why would you do any of it?! Just buy a USB “power bank”. It does it all for you and puts 5V out, at several amps of current capacity. And costs less than the time you spent conjuring far-off solutions :)

Comment: Good to know that there are plenty of circuits, again as I mentioned in another response, all the information I have ever gotten was that stepup voltage is more inefficient and problematic than step down. Don't know if that's true, but all I have to work from is what I've been told.... Also.... Why do you do make any circuit... I can buy ANYTHING you can make on Amazon, or from a cheap chinese site... Perhaps exploration, and discovery is a bad thing anymore? Because of some of the events in my life, I have to do everything I can to not be in my own head.